# Do Most short motifs and phrases end on the root

Tags: motif

This may be objective, but I'd like others input. 
Do most short phrases and motifs especially in blues and rock, end on the root. 
I think I've noticed that in most phrases, that the ending note is always the most important to the listener. and its usually the root (or third ) of the backing chord.
Yes, No ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Musical phrases normally end on a chord tone of some kind. The root is probably the most common (especially in rock, blues, and folk music) because it is the most stable tone in the chord. The fifth of the chord is probably the second most common note, followed by the third.

Often, musical phrases come in pairs known as "antecedent" and "consequent." It is sort of analogous to a question and answer, where the antecedent ends on the dominant and the consequent ends on the tonic. The two phrases together are called a "period."
http://openmusictheory.com/period.html

Comment: I'd say the third is more common than the fifth, which has shades of the dominant, so wouldn't be so convincing ( concerning plagal and perfect cadences, which is well connected).

Comment: @Tim Unless you're talking about jazz, I'm not sure that you are correct. I specifically pointed out the concept of antecedent/consequent phrases because the antecedent phrase will often end on the fifth (like in the example I linked to).

Comment: I'm being picky but 'root' and 'tonic' are not interchangeable. The *tonic* is the stable tone of the key. The root of any given chord isn't necessarily the tonic.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I agree that "tonic" and "root" are not interchangeable words, but I'm pretty sure I used the words properly here.

Comment: I think if you say 'the root is the most common... because it is the most stable tone in the *chord*' you will have your intended meaning.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Good point. I have changed the post to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great question and I have spent a lot of time trying to get the sense of the ending or goal tone of phrases in blues and jazz.

I often have felt that *avoiding the tonic* is characteristic in the style. That ending on the tonic is either too obvious, too bland, or too strong an ending that breaks the momentum. In no way is this a definitive statement from me, but I do present two examples that I think may illustrate the point. I concede the point up front that these are the "heads" and not necessarily indicative of how the phrasing would work in improvizations.

## Blue Monk emphasizing chord 3rds and 5ths

[image]

## C Jam Blue entirely the dominant

[image]

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to be asking about jazz. I deliberately chose these two because they are so strongly blues oriented.